# How to verify the redirection of link in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, redirect

I am clicking on a particular button/link which redirects to another page, I just want to verify that it is redirecting me to the correct page.

I am using Java and `onClick()`.

Comment: after clicking, check current_url

Comment: Your code trials and the relevant `HTML` please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to save in variable the link
2. After redirect you should save in variable `browser.getCurrentUrl()`
3. Compare those two variables.

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
expectedURL="{expected URL}";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for the button").click();
String redirectURL=driver.getCurrentUrl();
Assert.assertEquals(redirectURL,expectedURL);
```